# UIStackView : Image take most of the stack while Text shrink in fill distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7, uistoryboard

I want the image to take 1/3 of the UICollectionViewCell and the other 2/3 for the text.

I tried to change content hugging priority but no changes !

How to do it in UIStackview?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set a width constraint on the image view to be 1/3 of the stack view.

Comment: How it is done? I can do it manually by calculating the width/3 but i don't think that's what you meant!

Comment: `Imageview.frame.width = StackView.width/3`  ?

Comment: No, you need to add a `NSLayoutConstraint`.